# Mark duplicate headers in a fasta file

Tags: awk, sed, duplicates, fasta

I have a big Fasta file which I want to modify. It basically consists of many sequences with headers that start ">". My Problem is, that some of the Headers are not unique, even though the Sequences are unique.

Example:

> >acrdi|AD19082
>   STSTAFPLLTQFYGCAIIILVLAMCCSCLVYAMYFMNSSGLQTHESTVTQKVKDFSLQ
>   WLQPILFGCSWRHRLIAKSRRNRSKIQPMTGTEPPWNESKDAFENLKTWALNKQNRNCLL
>   EINFLEAKDFIVMCKDVVCFEEDDKDERNLNLCLKTLTEAFRFLRNCCAETPKNQSFVIS
>   SGVAKQAIEVILILLRPVFQEREKGTEVITDTIRSGLQLLGNTVVKNIDTQEFIWNCCCP
>   QFFLDVLLSRHHSIQDCLCMIIFNCLNQQRRLQLVNNPKIISQIVHLCADKSLLEWGYFI
>   LDCLICEGLFPDLYQGMEFDPLARIILLDLFQVKITDALDESSERTERTETPKELYASSL
>   NYLAEQFETYFIDIIQRLQQLDYSSNDFFQVLVVTRLLSLLSTSTGLKSSMTGLQDRASL
>   LETCVDLLRETSKPEAKAAFKRPGTSYWEYVLPTFP
>
> >acrdi|AD19082
>   MLRQSEPPWNESKDAFENLKTWALNKQNRNCLLEINFLEAKDFIVMCKDVVCFEEDDKDE
>   RNLNLCLKTLTEAFRFLRNCCAETPKNQSFVISSGVAKQAIEVILILLRPVFQEREKGTE
>   VITDTIRSGLQLLGNTVVKNIDTQEFIWNCCCPQFFLDVLLSRHHSIQDCLCMIIFNCLN
>   QQRRLQLVNNPKIISQIVHLCADKSLLEWGYFILDCLICEGLFPDLYQGMEFDPLARIIL
>   LDLFQVKITDALDESSERTERTETPKELYASSLNYLAEQFETYFIDIIQRLQQLDYSSND
>   FFQVLVVTRLLSLLSTSTGLKSSMTGLQDRASLLETCVDLLRETSKPEAKAAFSNVSSFP
>   HSVDSGRISPSHGFQRDLVRVIGNMCYQHFPNQEKVRELDGIPLLLDHCNIDDHNPYICQ
>   WAIFAIRNVLENNKENQDIVASIHPLGLADMSRLQQFGVDAVEFDGEKI

Now I want to find all duplicates in my big Fasta File and append numbers to the duplicates, so that I know which duplicate it is (1,2,3,...,x). When a new duplicate is found (one with another header), the counter should start from the beginning.

The output should be something like this:

> >acrdi|AD19082
>   STSTAFPLLTQFYGCAIIILVLAMCCSCLVYAMYFMNSSGLQTHESTVTQKVKDFSLQ
>   WLQPILFGCSWRHRLIAKSRRNRSKIQPMTGTEPPWNESKDAFENLKTWALNKQNRNCLL
>   EINFLEAKDFIVMCKDVVCFEEDDKDERNLNLCLKTLTEAFRFLRNCCAETPKNQSFVIS
>   SGVAKQAIEVILILLRPVFQEREKGTEVITDTIRSGLQLLGNTVVKNIDTQEFIWNCCCP
>   QFFLDVLLSRHHSIQDCLCMIIFNCLNQQRRLQLVNNPKIISQIVHLCADKSLLEWGYFI
>   LDCLICEGLFPDLYQGMEFDPLARIILLDLFQVKITDALDESSERTERTETPKELYASSL
>   NYLAEQFETYFIDIIQRLQQLDYSSNDFFQVLVVTRLLSLLSTSTGLKSSMTGLQDRASL
>   LETCVDLLRETSKPEAKAAFKRPGTSYWEYVLPTFP
>
> >acrdi|AD19082-1
>   MLRQSEPPWNESKDAFENLKTWALNKQNRNCLLEINFLEAKDFIVMCKDVVCFEEDDKDE
>   RNLNLCLKTLTEAFRFLRNCCAETPKNQSFVISSGVAKQAIEVILILLRPVFQEREKGTE
>   VITDTIRSGLQLLGNTVVKNIDTQEFIWNCCCPQFFLDVLLSRHHSIQDCLCMIIFNCLN
>   QQRRLQLVNNPKIISQIVHLCADKSLLEWGYFILDCLICEGLFPDLYQGMEFDPLARIIL
>   LDLFQVKITDALDESSERTERTETPKELYASSLNYLAEQFETYFIDIIQRLQQLDYSSND
>   FFQVLVVTRLLSLLSTSTGLKSSMTGLQDRASLLETCVDLLRETSKPEAKAAFSNVSSFP
>   HSVDSGRISPSHGFQRDLVRVIGNMCYQHFPNQEKVRELDGIPLLLDHCNIDDHNPYICQ
>   WAIFAIRNVLENNKENQDIVASIHPLGLADMSRLQQFGVDAVEFDGEKI

I would prefer a method with awk or sed, so that I can easily modify the code to run on all files in a directory.

I have to admit, that I am just starting to learn programming and parsing, but I hope this is not a stupid question.

THX in advance for the help.

Comment: Please use code blocks (Ctrl-k) rather than quoting your sample data. Also, I suspect that we don't need to see all those lines - it would be good if you reduced it to the bare minimum to demonstrate the issue. Is the input sorted, i.e. do the duplicate headers always appear one after the other?

Comment: I see you want solution from us. What have you tried? Try to do it yourself, if you get stuck. come back and, in new question, describe the problem that stops you from progressing.

Comment: use python and biopython package, everything you need is already there. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @TomFenech: thank you for your reply. I will do this in the future. The problem seems to be solved.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I tried it myself with some basic awk skripting, but I am currently starting and learning about programming. So I tried different things. Next time I will present what I tried and ask my Questions more specific.

Comment: @pianista Yeah Python would have been an option, but I wanted to do it with awk/sed as some kind of exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awk script:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="\n";
    ORS=RS=">";
} 
{
    name = $1;
    $1 = "";
    suffix = names[name] ? "-" names[name] : "";
    print name suffix $0, "\n";
    names[name]++;
}
```

The above uses the ">" as a record separator, and checks the first field (which is the header name that can be duplicated).  For each line it prints, it adds a suffix after the header name for each additional time the field appears (i.e. '-1' for the first dup, '-2' for the second...)